# drop_duplicates() with double brackets [[ ]]

Tags: python, pandas

I know what a horrible error message "not working" is, but it simply is that simple. I have a data set with a year and group identifier, `year` and `group`.

The code that I used to do was

```
df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates([['year', 'gvkey']]).set_index(['year', 'gvkey'], drop=True)
```

However, `df.index.is_unique` would return `false`. Puzzled, I looked at some slice of the data, and indeed:

```
>>> asd = df.head().reset_index()
>>> asd
Out[575]: 
   year  gvkey   sic state  naics
0  1966   1000  3089   NaN    NaN
1  1966   1000  3089   NaN    NaN
2  1972   1000  3089   NaN    NaN
3  1976   1000  3089   NaN    NaN
4  1984   1001  5812    OK    722
>>> asd.drop_duplicates([['year', 'gvkey']])
Out[576]: 
   year  gvkey   sic state  naics
0  1966   1000  3089   NaN    NaN
1  1966   1000  3089   NaN    NaN
4  1984   1001  5812    OK    722
```

However, following a random twitch, I also tried:

```
>>> asd.drop_duplicates(['year', 'gvkey'])
Out[577]: 
   year  gvkey   sic state  naics
0  1966   1000  3089   NaN    NaN
2  1972   1000  3089   NaN    NaN
3  1976   1000  3089   NaN    NaN
4  1984   1001  5812    OK    722
```

which gave me what I expected. Now I am ultimately confused. What exactly is the difference between the two notations - I always used the double brackets `[[]]`for slicing etc in python. Do I need to revise all my code or is this specific to `drop_duplicates()`?

Comment: Something to help understand this is that [['year', 'gvkey']] is not using a special double bracket notation, instead it is a list of columns enclosed in single brackets. This is clarified at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/indexing.html, where it states "You can pass a list of columns to [] to select columns in that order".  On the other hand, the subset argument of drop_duplicates should be a column label or sequence of labels, not a list of a list (or a sequence of a sequence of labels).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`drop_duplicates` expects a label or list of labels for its first argument. What you've created by putting two sets of brackets is a list of lists of labels. Pandas doesn't know what it's looking at when you do that.

> I always used the double brackets `[[]]` for slicing etc in python

Most likely, either you haven't been doing that as much as you thought, or your code is full of awkwardly formed data structures and weird code to work with them. Under normal circumstances (such as here), double brackets would be an error, and you would already have noticed. I would recommend rechecking the places you've used double brackets; I can't tell whether they should be changed just from this information.

Comment: Well, I was afraid I wouldn't notice.. just like here, the function still `worked` - as in, no error. However, the return seems to be following no expectations what so ever, even *if* one had added a sequence for some reason. I guess personally, I was just used to more import sanitation and got a bit frightened.

Anyhow, I noticed the only other place where I use double brackets a lot is slicing dataframes, as in `df2 = df[['col1', 'col2']]` - so I guess I'm lucky. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) when you pass a sequence to the first argument, which is `cols` in Pandas 0.13.1, you are giving the names of the columns to be considered when identifying the duplicates.

Therefore, the right sintax uses single brackets `[]`, `()`, because they will produce the sequence that you want. Using double brackets will produce a sequence of lists, in your case, and this will not represent the column labels that you are looking for.